# Leaflet - popup getContent for a customized popup

Tags: javascript, html, popup, leaflet

In Leaflet I've created a simple map with this HTML body structure:

```
<body>
    <h1>Leaflet webmap</h1>
    <div class="map" id="mainMap" role="main" tabindex="0"></div>
    <!-- modal-box to display full image -->
    <div id="modal-box" class="modal">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <img class="modal-content" id="modal-img" alt="Picture"/>
        <div id="modal-caption"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="../JS/fileJS.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
```

I've added to the map an array of points like this one:

```
var fontane = [
    ["Fontana1",45.38722539,10.48994631,"../fontane/Fontana1.jpg"],
    ["Fontana2,45.39481876,10.4869347,"../fontane/Fontana1.jpg"]
];
```

....
and, for each point, I've created and cutomized a popup with some text and a picture. Here is my js code:

```
var popupOptions = {
    maxWidth: '400',
    width: '200',
    className : 'custom-popup2'
    };
for (var i=0; i<fontane.length; i++) {
    var lat = fontane[i][1];
    var lon = fontane[i][2];
    var popupTitle = fontane[i][0];
    var popupImgPath = fontane[i][3];
    var popupText = "<h1>"+popupTitle+"</h1><br/><a href='http://www.website.fff/'>"+popupTitle+"</a><br/><br/><img class='img-popup' src="+popupImgPath+" alt='photo' style='width:150px'>";
    var popupBaloon = L.popup(popupOptions)
        .setContent(popupText);
    var fontanaLoc = new L.latLng(lat, lon);
    var fontana = new L.Marker(fontanaLoc, {icon: iconaFontana});
    mainMap.addLayer(fontana);
    fontana.bindPopup(popupBaloon);
}
```

This code works. Now I'd like to click on the picture inside the popup and open it in a new modal window.
I'm trying using the 'getContent' method applied to the popup in order to retrieve the html element that represents the image, but with no success. I can't understand what is the right syntax and what is my error. This is the complete, not working code.

```
var popupOptions = {
    maxWidth: '400',
    width: '200',
    className : 'custom-popup2'
    };
for (var i=0; i<fontane.length; i++) {
    var lat = fontane[i][1];
    var lon = fontane[i][2];
    var popupTitle = fontane[i][0];
    var popupImgPath = fontane[i][3];
    var popupText = "<h1>"+popupTitle+"</h1><br/><a href='http://www.website.fff/'>"+popupTitle+"</a><br/><br/><img class='img-popup' src="+popupImgPath+" alt='photo' style='width:150px'>";
    var popupBaloon = L.popup(popupOptions)
        .setContent(popupText);
    var fontanaLoc = new L.latLng(lat, lon);
    var fontana = new L.Marker(fontanaLoc, {icon: iconaFontana});
    mainMap.addLayer(fontana);
    fontana.bindPopup(popupBaloon);
    var modalBox = document.getElementById('modal-box');
    var modalImg = document.getElementById('modal-img');
    var modalCaption = document.getElementById('modal-caption');
    var popupImg2Mod = popupBaloon.getContent('img.img-popup');
    popupImg2Mod.onclick = function(){
        modalBox.style.display = "block";
        modalImg.src = popupImgPath.src;
        modalCaption.innerHTML = popupTitle;
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance, MZ